# Не отображается тень от ToolTip

Tags: c#, wpf

Не отображается тень от подсказки, подскажите как решить эту проблему?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#272e3b" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#3a404c" />
    <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#b3b3b3" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
                <Border x:Name="border"
                   Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                   CornerRadius="1"
                   BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                   BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                   SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                Focusable="False"
                                RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" MinHeight="10" MinWidth="50" 
                                TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" /> 
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ToolTipService.HasDropShadow" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="border" Value="1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем стиле нет никакой тени, которую можно отобразить, вот она и не отображается. Добавьте отрисовку тени и показывайте её. Можно это сделать, к примеру, так:
сначала зададим внешней границе `Margin`, чтобы наша тень не обрезалась при выводе:

```
<Border x:Name="border"
        Margin="10"
        ...
```

Теперь заменим код в тригере:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow"
             Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Effect"
                TargetName="border">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DropShadowEffect Color="Red" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: Ооо благодарю вас!! Спасибо!

Comment: @Елизавета, если ответ Вас удовлетворяет, пожалуйста, нажмите на галочку рядом с ответом, это действие отметить мой ответ как правильный.